# Solving equations as CSP

Tags: constraint-programming, optaplanner

I have a set of equations. I also have a set of values and the results for the equation.
Something like:

```
a + b + c = x
```

and some allocation might be:

```
1 + 1 + 1 = 3

2 + 3 + 4 = 9
```

However, the actual equations are much longer and may contain some functions, for example logarithms.

I now need to alter the result of a given set in a way that (1) the equation becomes equal to a specific value xx and (2) the parameters change as little as possible.

I thought I could solve this as a CSP by altering the eqation to

```
(a + ax) + (b + bx) + (c + cx) = xx
```

where a, b and c correspond to the old values and ax, bx and cx are the differences which need to be applied to the corresponding old values. And xx will be the result I want the equation to have. Note that a, b, c, xa, xb, cx etc. are all integer values and xx will always be within a certain distance to x, i.e. `xx - d < x < xx + d`.

In a CSP a, b, c and xx would be treated as Problem facts, ax, bx, cx would be treated as Planning variable and the equation `(a + ax) + (b + bx) + (c + cx) = xx` would be a hard constraint.
Minimizing all of ax, ab, ac would be a soft constraint.
I don't really see a Planning entity here.

```
global HardSoftScoreHolder scoreHolder;


rule "changeIsBad"
    when
        DeltaVariable($delta : delta)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -Math.abs(delta));
end

rule "equationMustBeEqual"
    // No idea?
end
```

But I can't figure out how to go on from here. Is Optaplanner feasible for this kind of problem? It seems all `PlanningVariable`s have to come from a List and have to be instances, whereas I only have integer values. Is my model correct?

Comment: A linear programming approach might be simpler. Have you considered it?

Comment: I don't think linear programming is feasible because the equations are not necessarily linear.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap each integer variable in an entity class, like this:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class MyEntity {

   private Integer myVariable;

   @PlanningVariable(...)
   public Integer getMyVariable() {...}
   ...
}
```

Additionally, use a planning entity range to define the range of each variable (because it differs per entity), see official docs section "4.3.5.2.2. ValueRangeProvider on a planning entity" (and don't use SwapMove's, only ChangeMove's I guess).

But overall, I am not 100% sure if this is the right tool for the job. I would be interested to know what your experience with this use case results into.

PS: Starting from 6.1.0.Beta1 (not yet released, but nightlies are available), we have IntValueRange as documented in [nightly docs](https://jenkins.mw.lab.eng.bos.redhat.com/hudson/view/Drools%20jBPM/view/Master/job/optaplanner/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/optaplanner-docs/target/docbook/publish/en-US/html_single/index.html#d0e2681) in section "4.3.5.2.4. ValueRangeFactory", which is more efficient for these kinds of use cases.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Having one ValueRangeProvider per variable makes sense to me. I'll let you know the results.